# DRY-er alternative for Rails "render and return" pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following pattern in my Rails controller:

```
def get_details
  # check params for valid input
  ...
  if !valid
    render :json, error_info, :status => 400 and return
  end

  begin
    ...
    ...
    ...
    render :json => result, :status => 200 and return
  rescue Exception => e
    if e.is_a? ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render :json => error_info, :status => 404 and return
    end
  end

end
```

Since render does not return, I have to add `and return` to every render call, and this does not seem too DRY to me. Is there an alternative to this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

**You can write it as follows**

```
def get_details
  # check params for valid input
  ...
  if !valid
    return render_with(error_info, 400)
  else
    begin
      ...
      ...
      ...
      return render_with(result, 200)
    rescue Exception => e
      if e.is_a? ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        return render_with(error_info, 404)
      end
    end    
  end
end

private

def render_with(result_info, status_code)
  render :json => result_info, :status => status_code
end
```

Comment: this way you'll render twice if valid == false because you only return  from `render_and_return` and not return from `get_details`

Comment: You got the right point. I forgot to wrap the begin block in else condition. Basically without that else condition, its not possible to return from `get_details` unless we dig deeper into rails core code.